# Можно ли как-то стандартными средствами упростить код?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу применить конъюнкцию ко всем значениям словаря. Набросал такой код:

```
d = {1: True, 2: True}

rez = True
for val in d.values():
    rez = rez and val
print(rez)
```

Выглядит он так себе... Можно ли красиво его как-то сделать? Может есть что из стандарта?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обычно для такого используется функция `all` - она проверяет, что все значения в итерируемом объекте истинные.

```
d = {1: True, 2: True}

rez = all(d.values())
print(rez)
```

Есть похожая функция `any` - она проверяет, что есть хотя бы один истинный элемент. Это соответствует оператору `or`.

Comment: О, не знал об этом. Я чувствовал, что min/max не очень подходят, и, возможно, есть что-то более подходящее.

Answer (score 5):

Конкретно в случае логического и (или) можно использовать min (max):

```
d = {1: True, 2: True}

rez = min(d.values())
print(rez)
```

Comment: Ппц, это ж элементарно... Как я сам не догадался) Как раз то что надо будет работать как логическое "И"